# Metal attachment for built-in light switch

Tags: toilet, smart-switch, motion-sensor

I was searching on the internet for a built-in light switch with a PIR-sensor. When surfing I found the sensor which I show in the picture. I was wondering what the metal attachment at the back of the light switch is meant for.

Also, I have an old house. The light switches I use are always mounted on the wall instead of built-in. I cannot find a switch which can be mounted on the wall. They are only available as a built-in variant. The light switch is meant for the toilet.

[image: light switch]

Comment: Without knowing much, I would think that picture was showing one piece of a two piece part.  As in that part plugs in to another part that is mounted/connected to a wall.

Comment: The switch should have instructions, which might tell you what the metal piece is.  Switches are usually mounted in boxes.  Most switches you buy today will be capable of being mounted in or on the wall, either way inside a box. If you want surface mounting you need to buy surface mount boxes.  The details depend on your country and your wall construction.

Comment: Without a brand/model number for that particular switch (and, preferably, a link to the manufacturer's site), you're only going to get guesses unless someone just happens to recognize it. Indicating where in the world you live would help, as well, as it may help people search for answers for you.

Comment: That looks rather UK electric form-factor (squarish) - where are you located (vaguely on the planet, not stalking level detail...) since electrics are often rather country/region specific.

Comment: @Ecnerwal i'm situated in the Netherlands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the hooking mechanism that clamps it into the cavity in a brick wall.

Under the cover will be a screw that when tightened will force the metal part outward into the sides of the cavity.

In addition to that the front plate will have screw holes and slots that will be compatible with electrical boxes.

The search term you are looking for however is "surface mount". Other terms to try would be "splash-proof" or "outdoor". Those are the usual reasons why one might forgo the built-in option.